# Realtime visualisation bottleneck with pyqtgraph / PlotCurveItem

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am currently using pyqtgraph to visualize realtime data for 64 independent data traces/plots. While the speed is realtively good, I noticed a serious slow down if the sample buffer length reaches beyond 2000 points. Profiling the following code yields that functions.py:1440(arrayToQPath) seems to have a major impact:

```
import numpy
import cProfile
import logging

import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt5 import QtCore,uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QTimer


def program(columns=8, samples=10000, channels=64):
    app = QApplication([])
    win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
    pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')
    win.resize(1280,768)
    win.ci.layout.setSpacing(0)
    win.ci.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

    data            = numpy.zeros((samples, channels+1))
    plots           = [win.addPlot(row=i/columns+1,col=i%columns) for i in range(channels)]
    curves          = list()

    x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, samples, endpoint=True)
    f = 2 # Frequency in Hz
    A = 1 # Amplitude in Unit
    y = A * numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*f*x).reshape((samples,1)) # Signal

    data[:,0]   = x
    data[:,1:]  = numpy.repeat(y, channels, axis=1)
    
    for chn_no,p in enumerate(plots, 1):
        c       = pg.PlotCurveItem(pen=(chn_no,channels * 1.3))
        p.addItem(c)
        curves.append((c, chn_no))
          
    def update():
        nonlocal data

        data[:,1:] = numpy.roll(data[:,1:], 100, axis=0)
            
        for curve,data_index in curves:
            curve.setData(data[:,0],data[:,data_index])

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(update)
    timer.start(30)
    return app.exec_()   


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    cProfile.run("program()", sort="cumtime")
    #program()
```

```
  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  533.660  533.660 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.053    0.053  533.660  533.660 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.018    0.018  533.607  533.607 pyqtgraph_test.py:11(program)
        1    9.181    9.181  532.209  532.209 {built-in method exec_}
     2709    0.015    0.000  401.728    0.148 GraphicsView.py:153(paintEvent)
     2709   15.572    0.006  401.696    0.148 {paintEvent}
   173376    0.193    0.000  345.725    0.002 debug.py:89(w)
   173376    1.599    0.000  345.532    0.002 PlotCurveItem.py:452(paint)
   173312    0.671    0.000  271.973    0.002 PlotCurveItem.py:440(getPath)
   173312    0.744    0.000  271.153    0.002 PlotCurveItem.py:416(generatePath)
   173312  266.888    0.002  270.409    0.002 functions.py:1440(arrayToQPath)
     2709    5.102    0.002  113.195    0.042 pyqtgraph_test.py:36(update)
   173440    0.193    0.000  100.616    0.001 PlotCurveItem.py:297(setData)
   173440    8.718    0.000  100.424    0.001 PlotCurveItem.py:337(updateData)
```

So almost 1.5 ms per call is spent. Playing around with the arrayToQPath I noticed that soley the `ds >> path` within the arrayToQPath seems to consum most of the time (results with that line commented out):

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  190.847  190.847 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.050    0.050  190.847  190.847 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.017    0.017  190.796  190.796 pyqtgraph_test.py:11(program)
        1    7.438    7.438  189.395  189.395 {built-in method exec_}
     2221    4.165    0.002   88.497    0.040 pyqtgraph_test.py:36(update)
     2221    0.010    0.000   86.830    0.039 GraphicsView.py:153(paintEvent)
     2221   11.494    0.005   86.806    0.039 {paintEvent}
   142208    0.152    0.000   77.941    0.001 PlotCurveItem.py:297(setData)
   142208    4.500    0.000   77.789    0.001 PlotCurveItem.py:337(updateData)
```

ds is a QtCore.QDataStream and path is QPainterPath. However, the reason why the >> operation takes so much time completely eludes me. So I am looking for a possiblitly to speed up the rendering and would like to stick to pyqtgraph i.e. not perform a switch to e.g. vispy right now.

The original functions.py arrayToQPath:

```
def arrayToQPath(x, y, connect='all'):
    """Convert an array of x,y coordinats to QPainterPath as efficiently as possible.
    The *connect* argument may be 'all', indicating that each point should be
    connected to the next; 'pairs', indicating that each pair of points
    should be connected, or an array of int32 values (0 or 1) indicating
    connections.
    """

    ## Create all vertices in path. The method used below creates a binary format so that all
    ## vertices can be read in at once. This binary format may change in future versions of Qt,
    ## so the original (slower) method is left here for emergencies:
        #path.moveTo(x[0], y[0])
        #if connect == 'all':
            #for i in range(1, y.shape[0]):
                #path.lineTo(x[i], y[i])
        #elif connect == 'pairs':
            #for i in range(1, y.shape[0]):
                #if i%2 == 0:
                    #path.lineTo(x[i], y[i])
                #else:
                    #path.moveTo(x[i], y[i])
        #elif isinstance(connect, np.ndarray):
            #for i in range(1, y.shape[0]):
                #if connect[i] == 1:
                    #path.lineTo(x[i], y[i])
                #else:
                    #path.moveTo(x[i], y[i])
        #else:
            #raise Exception('connect argument must be "all", "pairs", or array')

    ## Speed this up using >> operator
    ## Format is:
    ##    numVerts(i4)   0(i4)
    ##    x(f8)   y(f8)   0(i4)    <-- 0 means this vertex does not connect
    ##    x(f8)   y(f8)   1(i4)    <-- 1 means this vertex connects to the previous vertex
    ##    ...
    ##    0(i4)
    ##
    ## All values are big endian--pack using struct.pack('>d') or struct.pack('>i')

    path = QtGui.QPainterPath()

    #profiler = debug.Profiler()
    n = x.shape[0]
    # create empty array, pad with extra space on either end
    arr = np.empty(n+2, dtype=[('x', '>f8'), ('y', '>f8'), ('c', '>i4')])
    # write first two integers
    #profiler('allocate empty')
    byteview = arr.view(dtype=np.ubyte)
    byteview[:12] = 0
    byteview.data[12:20] = struct.pack('>ii', n, 0)
    #profiler('pack header')
    # Fill array with vertex values
    arr[1:-1]['x'] = x
    arr[1:-1]['y'] = y

    # decide which points are connected by lines
    if eq(connect, 'all'):
        arr[1:-1]['c'] = 1
    elif eq(connect, 'pairs'):
        arr[1:-1]['c'][::2] = 1
        arr[1:-1]['c'][1::2] = 0
    elif eq(connect, 'finite'):
        arr[1:-1]['c'] = np.isfinite(x) & np.isfinite(y)
    elif isinstance(connect, np.ndarray):
        arr[1:-1]['c'] = connect
    else:
        raise Exception('connect argument must be "all", "pairs", "finite", or array')

    #profiler('fill array')
    # write last 0
    lastInd = 20*(n+1)
    byteview.data[lastInd:lastInd+4] = struct.pack('>i', 0)
    #profiler('footer')
    # create datastream object and stream into path

    ## Avoiding this method because QByteArray(str) leaks memory in PySide
    #buf = QtCore.QByteArray(arr.data[12:lastInd+4])  # I think one unnecessary copy happens here

    path.strn = byteview.data[12:lastInd+4] # make sure data doesn't run away
    try:
        buf = QtCore.QByteArray.fromRawData(path.strn)
    except TypeError:
        buf = QtCore.QByteArray(bytes(path.strn))
    #profiler('create buffer')
    ds = QtCore.QDataStream(buf)

    ds >> path
    #profiler('load')

    return path
```

---

EDIT:

Taking a closer look into QT revealed that the QDataStream >> operator in C++ is comparable slow. it is so slow, that overwriting the positions of the elements inside an old QtGui.QPainterPath() instead of creating a new one is faster:

```
import timeit
import struct
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore

no_trys = 1000

def test(pass_data, samples = 10000):
    path = QtGui.QPainterPath()

    n = samples
    # create empty array, pad with extra space on either end
    arr = np.zeros(n+2, dtype=[('x', '>f8'), ('y', '>f8'), ('c', '>i4')])
    # write first two integers
    byteview = arr.view(dtype=np.ubyte)
    byteview.data[12:20] = struct.pack('>ii', n, 0)

    # write last 0
    lastInd = 20*(n+1)
    # create datastream object and stream into path
    path.strn = byteview.data[12:lastInd+4] # make sure data doesn't run away
    buf = QtCore.QByteArray.fromRawData(path.strn)
    ds = QtCore.QDataStream(buf)

    path.reserve(n)
    if pass_data:
        ds >> path

    def func1():
        nonlocal path

        ds = QtCore.QDataStream(buf)
        ds >> path

    def func2():
        nonlocal path
        values = [(i,i,i) for i in range(samples)]
        map(path.setElementPositionAt, values)

    print(timeit.timeit(func1, number=no_trys))
    print(timeit.timeit(func2, number=no_trys))


test(True)
```

results in 1.32 s for the DataStream and 0.9 s for the map(path.setElementPositionAt, values).

profiling the following C++ snippet results in over 8 s on my machine:

```
#include <QtCore/QDataStream>
#include <QtGui/QPainterPath>

int function2(const int samples)
{
    auto size = 8 + samples * 20 + 4;

    std::vector<char> data(size, 0);

    memcpy(data.data(), &samples, 4);

    QByteArray buf(QByteArray::fromRawData(data.data(), size));
    QDataStream ds(buf);

    float ret;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < samples; counter++)
    {
        int type = 1;
        double x = 0, y = 0;

        ds >> type >> x >> y;
        ret = type + x + y;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{    
    const int samples = 10000;
    const int tries = 10000;
    int ret = 0;

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (auto counter = 0; counter < tries; counter++)
    {
        ret += function2(samples);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;

    std::cout << "done\n";
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " s\n";
    std::cout << ret;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a pyqtgraph maintainer; I wanted to thank you for this dive into profiling of arrayToQPath.  The PySide devs have indicated they are very open and receptive toward making performance improvements, so having a concrete example I can go to them with is very helpful.  I'm sorry I don't have a good workaround here for you, and if you've come up with one, we would be grateful if you submitted a PR.

Comment: Core issue is that QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &stream, QPainterPath &path) basically iterates over all entries and does "ds >> type >> x >> y;" - it is a perfect example there OOP lead to a design which is very "data unfriendly": 3 different operators are called per entry with multiple checks included. The OGL implementation copies the whole data block-wise which is much more efficient. Maybe one could use readRawData to process data block-wise afterwards. However, this will mostlikely not pass code review as it defeats the built-in safeties of QDataStream.

Comment: TL;DR: for this usecase using OGL is actually a damn good idea IMHO. No need for the built-in safeties if the data are coming from the same machine/memory layout and everything is processed blockwise + one uses a dedicated rendering engine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow OGL?

Comment: oh, OGL = OpenGL, i should have caught that.  Not all the widgets we plot to support openGL unfortunately, so I'll have to think of another solution to get around this issue, or find another performance boost.

Comment: using QPainter::drawLines instead of QPainter::drawPath might be an option. Not sure if any of the QPainterPath functionality could not be reproduced using the drawLines approach instead.

Comment: I'm not sure historically what the reasons are; but QPainterPath lets us handle disconnected arrays nicely, which drawLines may work for.  PythonQwt uses QPainter.drawPolyline (which I don't think handles discontinuities), so that may be an alternative if you have `connect='all'`.  We're likely going to start exploring higher performing alternatives soon.  If you have suggestions, please feel free to start a discussion on the pyqtgraph repo.

Comment: I just implemented a large speedup for the use-case of "connect='all'", it's not merged in master, but if this is something that still impacts you, would you mind giving this a try? https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/pull/1796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to activate the OpenGL mode i.e. install the **PyOpenGL** and **PyOpenGL-accelerate** modules and enable the OpenGL use. This way the createPath part is completely left out. I simply added the following block in my application:

```
try:
    import OpenGL
    pg.setConfigOption('useOpenGL', True)
    pg.setConfigOption('enableExperimental', True)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Enabling OpenGL failed with {e}. Will result in slow rendering. Try installing PyOpenGL.")
```

With that my PC can draw 64 traces with 30000 datapoints without breaking a sweat.

Comment: With pyqtgraph 0.12.0, and adoption of Qt6, we have phased out our usage of QGLWidget and used QOpenGLWidgets instead.  We've run into a problematic bug on Windows; so while this solution here can get around some problems, it's by no means a general fix.

Comment: @OgiMoore just tried this on Windows, rendering is now infinitely more slow than before. I assume this might be a result of the bug you mention?

Comment: Generally speaking, I would encourage pyqtgraph users to stay away from our opengl implementation unless it addresses a specific need.  With recent versions of PyQtGraph (0.13+) the line plot performance is quite fast, even with thick lines.

To get a sense of how many data points pyqtgraph can render, run the PlotSpeedTest example, it has a parameter tree that you can adjust the number of points and so on.