# why pyqt5 GUI will be freeze when I use infinite while loop?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyserial, pyqtgraph

I receive live data from the serial port and when the 'start' push button, will be clicked we must be read the data. I receive the data correctly but the GUI freeze and then I cant plot them into a pyqtgraph that merges into the QgraphicView. then I will have 2 questions:

1. what must be I do, that my GUI in not freeze?
2. what must be I do to plotting the live data into the merging pyqtgraph?
   my main code in the below (note that the GUI code was made by QtDesigner and this is into the other code):
   (if you can help me for merging pyqtgraph with QgraphicView I thankful to learn it)

```py
tempf = []
shc = []

ser = serial.Serial('COM13', 9600)

class SetUI_main(Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.draw)

    def draw(self):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        sh = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            data = ser.readline()
            temp = float(data.decode())
            sh += 0.6
            shc.append(sh)
            tempf.append(temp)
            print(tempf)
            #print(shc)
            self.graphicsView.plot(tempf,shc)

    def start(self):
        s = 's'.encode('ascii')
        ser.write(s)
        print('Start')
        self.timer.start(2000)

    def connector(self):
        self.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(self.start)
```

Comment: It looks like you want the same code to run every tenth of a second. You should set up a timer which repeatedly times out every tenth of a second to call a method which itself does some work and returns as soon as possible.

Comment: can you help me a bit more?! please tell me what am I doind? if you can share me a code

Comment: Maybe taking a look at the first code listing of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63855707/realtime-visualisation-bottleneck-with-pyqtgraph-plotcurveitem might give you an idea how to achieve an interactive GUI. The trick is to use a timer to call the update frequently.